# Getting the mount point in Chrome from StorageUnitInfo

Tags: google-chrome-app

I'm trying to find the mount point of a piece of removable media when it is inserted into a system using a Chrome App. The code I have successfully detects -- on both OSX and CrOS -- the insertion and gets a [StorageUnitInfo](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/system_storage#type-StorageUnitInfo). However, the `id` doesn't really correspond to anything useable (AFAICT). I tried using the `id` with [`restoreEntry()`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem#method-restoreEntry), but it's not even in the same format. The `name` of the same piece of media varies between operating systems and isn't necessarily useful for mapping the mount point. Is there a way to use StorageUnitInfo to get an Entry or a string representation of the mount point's path?

Here's an example StorageUnitInfo that I received from my app:

```
Object {capacity: 3960995840, id: "492CD8BA-2BC8-4C38-9646-698BF8904568", name: "NO NAME", type: "removable"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that, given the provided APIs. The ID is unique to this API.

Makes me wonder what the purpose of the `chrome.system.storage` API even is, besides providing a "safely remove" operation.
Querying available capacity is not enabled in stable, and you can only get the total capacity of storage and be able to (try to) eject it.